# Java SchedulerExecutor

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

Recently I wrote code that had to limit request throughput. I used `ScheduleExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` and I believed that it should do the work (It did!) but I wrote some test to check time of scheduled task and i was amazed. First few tasks weren't scheduled as javadoc explain with n*period. Can anyone explain me what am I missing?
If it work that way then why it is not mentioned in javadoc? And then question is how exactly scheduler work? 
I would like to avoid looking into sources:)

Example:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class ExecutorTest {
    Executor executor;
    ScheduledExecutorService schedulingExecutor;
    BlockingQueue<LocalTime> times;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new ExecutorTest().start();
    }

    public ExecutorTest() {
        schedulingExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        times = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        schedulingExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::executeTask, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        LocalTime nextEvaluatedTime = times.take();
        LocalTime time = nextEvaluatedTime;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(String.format(String.join(" ", "recorded time: %d", "calculated proper time: %d", "diff: %d"),
                                      time.toNanoOfDay(),
                                      nextEvaluatedTime.toNanoOfDay(),
                                      Duration.between(nextEvaluatedTime, time).toNanos()));
            nextEvaluatedTime = time.plus(50, ChronoUnit.MILLIS);
            time = times.take();
        }
    }

    private void executeTask() {
       executor.execute(() -> {
          times.add(LocalTime.now());
       });
    }
}
```

If you run this program you could see that few first time wasn't recorded as expected. Why?